# Applying a theme for a Telerik RadMultiComboBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, telerik

I have a vb.net application with many data-entry forms.  On some of these forms a Telerik RadMultiComboBox control is used.  I want the VisualStudio2012Light theme applied to all of these controls.  I have no trouble applying the theme on all forms but one.  On that one form, VisualStudio2012Light is not an option. I change the theme thru Properties...StyleSheet...ThemeName in the Visual Studio designer. I can manually enter it by typing it in but it does not stick and goes back to the default theme.

Using Visual Studio 2022 and version 2022.2.622.40 of Telerik.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe compare the designer code of a form that does work with the one that doesn't.  See what's different.  Do you have RadMultiComboBox on forms that work, or just the troublesome one?

Comment: I have since found out that this application was originally developed in VS2019 then upgraded to 2022.  Telerik controls were updated to 2022.3.921.48 but due to problems manipulating the controls in the UI, they were downgraded to 2022.2.622.40.  So this might be a problem with Telerik.  I will post on their forum.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RadForm, the ThemeName property should work. You can drag-drop the VisualStudio2012Light theme from the ToolBox to the RadForm. Check the following image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xnq2.png)
Then from the Visual Studio Properties window, you can navigate to the ThemeName property and set it to the desired theme. The last step is to apply the theme to all controls from the smart tag of the RadForm. This should do the trick:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVMyj.png)